# yum complete transaction with CentOS 6.5 server

Tags: linux, updates, yum

I want update my server. I am using Linux CentOS 6.5

I ran yum update and got the following errors:

```
Error: Package: xorg-x11-drv-nv-2.1.20-4.el6.x86_64 (@base)
       Requires: xserver-abi(videodrv-13) >= 1
       Removing: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.13.0-23.1.el6.centos.x86_64 (@updates)
           xserver-abi(videodrv-13) = 1
       Updated By: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-25.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
           Not found
Error: Package: xorg-x11-drv-modesetting-0.5.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@base)
       Requires: xserver-abi(videodrv-13) >= 1
       Removing: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.13.0-23.1.el6.centos.x86_64 (@updates)
           xserver-abi(videodrv-13) = 1
       Updated By: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-25.el6.centos.x86_64 (updates)
           Not found
```

I then saw that I needed to run yum-complete-transaction and it is asking me if I can remove 380 packages.

```
 xz-lzma-compat                                   x86_64                  4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el6                   @anaconda-CentOS-201106060106.x86_64/6.0                   21 k
 yum                                              noarch                  3.2.29-43.el6.centos                               @updates                                                  4.5 M
 yum-plugin-fastestmirror                         noarch                  1.1.30-17.el6_5                                    @updates                                                   53 k
 yum-utils                                            noarch                     1.1.30-17.el6_5                                        @updates                                                  302 k

Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================
Remove      380 Package(s)

Installed size: 1.1 G
Is this ok [y/N]: n
```

My question is if I were to select y, would that negatively affect the yum update that I would do on the server?

Comment: If it is trying to remove things like `yum` that's absolutely not correct and will almost certainly **horribly** break your system.

Comment: Well I don't want yum to be removed then.

Comment: I actually had more to the errors but there are too many to list on here.

Comment: Hello, just to clarify, are you trying to run yum upgrade to go from centos 6.5 -> 6.6 ? What command are you running exactly. Also could you run cat /etc/redhat-release to confirm what version you're running? It's possible that you have to run yum clean all before attempting your yum upgrade command.

Comment: The command I am trying to run exactly is yum update. I just did that command and I am running CentOS 6.6 not 6.5 sorry.

Comment: I did that. I ran yum clean all and then I ran yum update and I am not getting the message that says this what you update and the options y or n.

Comment: I also got this too:

yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch is a duplicate with yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-17.el6_5.noarch
yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch is a duplicate with yum-utils-1.1.30-17.el6_5.noarch

Comment: Did the system use to be centos 6.5? or did it use to be centos 6.4 or something like that? If so I think I have the solution for you to do a clean upgrade....

Comment: I am going to be honest with you. I think it used to be a 6.4 but I can't say for sure. I am going to have to ask a co-worker of mine to see if he made any upgrades that I don't know about.

Comment: What would your solution be if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: so, you want to check the contents of all files matching  /etc/yum.repos.d/mirrorlists/centos-* or /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-* ( depending on if you're using a mirror list or not ) ... make sure they point to 6.6 instead of 6.4 or any other older version. To ensure your yum cache is clean run yum clean all; yum clean metadata, and finally do a yum upgrade. Let me know how that it looking